# ggplot2 heatmap plot not equally spread onto background theme

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make simple heat map using ggplot, but the heatmap I get is weird. the heatmap plot spreads unequally on the background and I don't know how to fix this.

I have already tried this following code which gave me the heat map plot, but with weird result.

```
 ggplot(data = vmd, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
     geom_tile(aes(fill = val)) +
     scale_fill_gradientn(colours = mycol)
```

[image]

Comment: `+ coord_equal()`

Answer (score 0):

Someone already said that you can use `+coord_equal()` to fix the ratio of the X and Y axis.

If you talk about the NA, what I usually do in this case is to clean the data before plotting it.

```
vmd_clean = vmd[complete.cases(vmd),]
```

You can also dig into the `subset(...)` function.

There might be a solution built in ggplot2, but I don't know about it. If someone knows about it, I'd love to learn about.